# React Native onPress doesn't work on IOS, but on Web it does

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

community!

I am building my first React-Native app and I have problem running this part of the code on IOS.

There is a function passed to onPress prop of a Button, that works on web but when I tried it on IOS nothing happends when pressing the button. The function should update the state of the parent component so it render's the next part of the Game form.

(There is a complete screen code sample at the bottom and you can also check the entire app in this git repository: https://github.com/dogaruemiliano/claim-app)

```
const handlePress = () => {
    handleSubmit(maxPoints)
}

return (
    <>
        <Text style={styles.header}>Max points</Text>
        <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            ref={inputRef}
            value={maxPoints}
            onChangeText={value => setMaxPoints(value)}
            keyboardType="numeric"
        />
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
            behavior='padding'
            >
            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn}>
                    <Button
                        title="Next"
                        onPress={() => handlePress()} // here is the problem
                        color={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? COLORS.white : COLORS.black} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>     
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </>
)
```

The function called in the handlePress,

```
handleSubmit(maxPoints)
```

is received in the props of the component from the parent component that handles the logic up to the point where it send a POST request to the API.

Here is the complete code of the screen for New Game Creation.

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { SafeAreaView, View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, Platform, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native'
import { TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'

import Navbar from '../components/Navbar'
import COLORS from '../constants/Colors'

import { createGame } from '../actions'

const MaxPointsInput = (props) => {
    const { handleSubmit } = props

    const [maxPoints, setMaxPoints] = useState("")
    const [done, setDone] = useState(false)
    const inputRef = useRef(null)

    const handlePress = () => {
        setDone(true) // to test if function is executed
        handleSubmit(maxPoints)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        inputRef.current.focus()
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <Text style={styles.header}>Max points</Text>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                ref={inputRef}
                value={maxPoints}
                onChangeText={value => setMaxPoints(value)}
                keyboardType="numeric"
            />
            <KeyboardAvoidingView
                behavior='padding'
                >
                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn}>
                        <Button
                            title={done ? "Done..." : "Next"}
                            onPress={() => handlePress()}
                            color={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? COLORS.white : COLORS.black} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>     
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </>
    )
}

const PlayersInput = (props) => {
    const { handleSubmit, currentUser } = props
    const [players, setPlayers] = useState([])
    const [nameInputValue, setNameInputValue] = useState("")
    const inputRef = useRef()

    useEffect(() => {
        inputRef.current.focus()
    }, [])

    const addPlayer = () => {
        setNameInputValue("")
        setPlayers([...players, nameInputValue])
        inputRef.current.value = ""
        inputRef.current.focus()
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Text style={styles.header}>Players</Text>
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <Text>Player #1: {currentUser.attributes.name} (you)</Text>
                {players.map((player, index) => {
                    return(
                        <Text key={player}>Player #{index + 2}: {player}</Text>
                    )
                })}
                <Text>Player #{players.length + 2}</Text>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    ref={inputRef}
                    value={nameInputValue}
                    onChangeText={value => setNameInputValue(value)}
                    keyboardType="numeric"
                />
            </View>
            <KeyboardAvoidingView
                behavior='padding'
                style={{ marginBottom: 200, flex: 1 }}
            >   
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn}>
                    <Button
                        title="Add"
                        onPress={addPlayer}
                        color={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? COLORS.white : COLORS.black} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn}>
                    <Button
                        title="Done"
                        onPress={() => handleSubmit(players)}
                        color={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? COLORS.white : COLORS.black} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </>
    )
}

const Confirmation = (props) => {
    const { handleSubmit, maxPoints, players, currentUser } = props
    return (
        <>
            <Text style={styles.header}>Details</Text>
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <Text>Max points: {maxPoints}</Text>
                <Text>Players: </Text>
                <Text>1. {currentUser.attributes.name}</Text>

                {players.map((player, index) => {
                    return (
                        <Text key={player}>{index + 2}. {player}</Text>
                    )
                })}

            </View>
            <KeyboardAvoidingView
                behavior='padding'
            >
                <View style={styles.btn}>
                    <Button
                        title="Confirm"
                        onPress={() => handleSubmit({maxPoints, players}, currentUser)}
                        color={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? COLORS.white : COLORS.black} />
                </View>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </>
    )
}


function NewGameScreen(props) {
    const { navigation, currentUser, createGame } = props
    const [maxPoints, setMaxPoints] = useState("")
    const [players, setPlayers] = useState([])
    const [showMaxPointsInput, setShowMaxPointsInput] = useState(true)
    const [showPlayersInput, setShowPlayersInput] = useState(false)
    const [showConfirmation, setShowConfirmation] = useState(false)

    const handleMaxPointsSubmit = (value) => {
        setMaxPoints(value)
        setShowMaxPointsInput(false)
        setShowPlayersInput(true)
    }
    const handlePlayersSubmit = (value) => {
        setPlayers(value)
        setShowPlayersInput(false)
        setShowConfirmation(true)
    }

    const handleConfirmaton = (data, currentUser) => {
        createGame({data, currentUser, navigation})
    }

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.inner}>
                { showMaxPointsInput && 
                    <MaxPointsInput handleSubmit={handleMaxPointsSubmit}/>
                }
                { showPlayersInput &&
                    <PlayersInput handleSubmit={handlePlayersSubmit} currentUser={currentUser} />
                }
                {
                    showConfirmation &&
                    <Confirmation maxPoints={maxPoints} currentUser={currentUser} players={players} handleSubmit={handleConfirmaton} />
                }
            </View>
            <Navbar navigation={navigation} />
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        marginHorizontal: 'auto',
        marginTop: 48
    },
    inner: {
        padding: 24,
        paddingBottom: 80,
        justifyContent: "center",
        width: (Platform.OS === 'web' ? 300 : null),
        marginTop: 48,
    },
    btn: {
        borderRadius: 6,
        marginTop: 12,
        marginBottom: 2,
        backgroundColor: COLORS.black,
    },
    btnOutline: {
        borderRadius: 6,
        marginTop: 12,
        backgroundColor: COLORS.transparent,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: COLORS.black,
        color: COLORS.black,
    },
    header: {
        fontSize: 32,
        textAlign: 'center',
        marginBottom: 32,
    },
    scrollView: {
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
    },
    input: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        height: 50,
        fontSize: 32,
        marginBottom: 20,
        borderBottomWidth: 2,
        borderColor: '#dbdbdb',
        paddingBottom: 5,
    },
})
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        currentUser: state.currentUser
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        createGame: (props) => dispatch(createGame(props))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NewGameScreen)
```

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code block, it seems that you are wrapping a button inside a `TouchableOpacity` Component which is imported from react-native-gesture-handler.

1. You can refactor code into, like removing unwanted wrapping with Touchable Elements if not required.

```
 <View style={styles.btn}>
   <Button
   title={done ? "Done..." : "Next"}
   onPress={handlePress}
   color={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'white' : 'black'} />
 </View>
```

2. Import `TouchableOpacity` from react-native

```
import { Text, View, StyleSheet ,TextInput, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Yes, that was it. Somehow VSCode adds import automatically, don't really understand how and why, but it was just me being a noob. Thank you for your time!